# How to convert String "Weeelcommme tttto Unnnnnicommmerce" to "Welcome to Unicommerce" in Java?

Tags: java, regex, dictionary

**Input**

```
Input string = "Weeelcommme tttto Unnnnnicommmerce";
```

**Desired output**

```
Welcome to Unicommerce
```

This is not the same as removing duplicates from String since we want Both "**e**" and "**m**" also. Removing duplicates using `HashSet` gives us unique elements only.

Comment: You need to have a dictionary in this situation, You cannot know what makes a word valid.

Comment: To achieve this behavior, you program need to "know" English. You will need to use a dictionary, and you are essentially writing an auto correct function

Comment: tri-gram frequency analysis on words paired with a dictionary will give you a probabilistic answer, thats the best you'll get no guarantee. You'll need a pretty large dictionary tho as it seems your matching more than english words

Comment: Knowing English is not sufficient.  "Unicommerce" is not an English word.  This is actually a difficult problem.  I would ask ... why do you actually need to do this?  Wouldn't the regular approach of spelling checking and *suggesting* corrections to the user be a better idea?

Comment: You are going to need some sort of dictionary here, a pure regex alone isn't enough (q.v. my downvoted and now deleted answer below).

Comment: Oh is it so complicated ...This was asked in an interview ...

Answer (score 2):

There are many way to do auto completions, ALL of which require some sort of dictionary. A simple algorithm to use would be trigram frequency analysis. I will describe an example below.

#### Dictionary

Consider the dictionary

```
1. hello
2. he
3. my
4. name
```

#### Input

Now consider the input `heello mmy nnamme`.

#### Build the Trigrams

We need to build the trigrams of each element in the dictionary.

```
1. hello = hel ell llo
2. he = he
3. my = my
4. name = nam ame
```

Then we split each word and build its trigrams

```
1. heello = hee eel ell llo
2. mmy = mmy
3. nnamme = nna nam amm mme
```

The we build a vector and compute the cos similarity between the two.

#### Side Note

All trigrams are hashed into unique integers before comparison, further trigrams should be thought of as integers.

#### Comparisons

Considering the function `z(v1, v2) = c` where z computes the cosine similarity of v1, and v2. Then `v1 = (hee, eel, ell, llo)` and `v2 = (hel, ell,llo, 0)`. Now the cosine similarity will tell how "similar" these vectors are. Doing this for all elements in the dictionary and picking the word with the cosine similarity closest to 1 will be the best matched word. I won't do the arithmetic out because it is quite long but [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) you can find the formula for the similarity.

#### Other Notes

This method of trigram frequency is used very much in language processing to determine what language a given text is in and was applied to early speech to text applications. I hope you see from above how the trigrams help you find the answer. I think the only problem you will run into is finding a dictionary as "Unicommerce" is not a word in an english dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a dictionary hash of collapsed words to their complete counterparts, and use a simple algorithm to remove duplicate letters from candidate words.

```
a:[a]
aple:[apple]
ardvark:[aardvark]
to:[to/too]
unicomerce:[Unicommerce]
welcome:[welcome]
```

When performing your transformation, first split your sentence into words, then create a lookup reference by removing duplicate letters, then retrieve the expanded words for each de-duplicated word.

So, "Weeelcommme tttto Unnnnnicommmerce" first becomes ["welcome","to","unicomerce"], and each member is expanded from your dictionary to build "welcome to Unicommerce" or possibly "welcome too Unicommerce".  You'll have an imperfect solution, and could use a grammar checker to help disambiguate words, and may end up with words not found in your dictionary, but it would at least be a viable starting point.